# Robbie the Robot and the sequence

Tags: combinatorics

Robbie the robot is generating a sequence of non-negative integers that starting from $0$ so that each term after the first term is either $0$, or the previous term plus $1$, modulo $1000$ (If the previous term is $999$, the next term is $0$). THe robot stops generating the sequence when the number $999$ is written exactly three times. An example sequence is

$0,1,2,...999,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,3,0...$

Let $N$ denote the number of possible sequences the robot can generate that contain the number $0$ exactly $2018$ times. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000$.

I'm frankly not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider expressing each full sequence instead by the "tops" of each run.  In your example above, rather than writing it as $0,1,2,\dots,999,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,3$ you could have instead written it as $999,2,0,3$.

Comment: For the first half of the problem, you should have an answer in the form of $\binom{\square}{\square}\square^{\square}$.  For the second half of the problem, we are tasked with calculating the previous result modulo $1000$.  A hint for that step, look at which numbers are close to $1000$ to simplify calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new sequence that is the last number before each $0$ plus the last number of your sequence.  Can you see the bijection between this set of sequences and the sequences you ask about?  We are told there are three $999$s in the new sequence, one of them is the last number, every other term is less than $999$ and there are $2018$ terms.  How many sequences can you make following those rules?

Added: you choose $2$ places for $999$ out of the first $2017$ terms, then each other term has $999$ choices, giving a total of ${2017 \choose 2}999^{2015}$. To get this $\bmod 1000$ note that $999 \equiv -1 \pmod {1000}$ so we want $\frac 12\cdot 17 \cdot 16 \cdot (-1)^{2015}=-136=864 \pmod {1000}$

Comment: I'm not really sure what a bijection is? Can you elaborate?

Comment: A [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) is a function that is one-to-one and onto.  Every element in the domain goes to a different element in the range and every element in the range is the image of an element in the domain.  It means that the domain and range have the same number of members, so you can count either one you want.  I find the new sequences easier to think about how to count because you can think about where the $999$s are

Comment: So how many sequences could we make? I'm thinking that the answer is $499$.

Comment: @Skupp:  No, it is far larger than that.  You have to choose two places for the first two $999$s out of $2017$.  How many ways to do that?  If you are the same as OP, there are instructions on the FAQ for how to merge your accounts.

Comment: I am not the OP, but I think I have a rough idea of the answer. Does it have to do with the Choose Function?

Comment: @Skupp: see the update

Comment: So the answer = 864